# Why this alarm handling example result in different output in Linux and Macos?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, operating-system, signals

So I was studying signal handling, particularly the SIGALRM, in the Unix system and testing the following example.

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    static int beeps = 0;
    printf("BEEP\n");
    if (beeps < 4) {
        beeps += 1;
        fork();
        alarm(1);
    } else {
        printf("BOOM!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler);
    alarm(1);
    while (1);
    exit(0);
}
```

In Linux, the output works the same as I expected.

```
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
BEEP
BOOM!
```

However, when i try to compile and run the same program in Mac OS, the result is completely different.

```
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BEEP
BOOM!
```

For troubleshooting, I rechecked to see whether the fork is done correctly and looked into disassembler's result. All seems correct and doesn't perform any unexpected optimization.

For spec, I used Linux version 6.2.2 with gcc v12.2.1 and MacOS (intel) Ventura with apple clang v14.0.0,all with no optimization options on.

I'm speculating that this might be related to the handling issues provided by the OS but I simply don't have a clue. I'll appreciate if someone could provide some useful documentations or manuals or blogs that I can look into. Huge thanks.

Comment: You _rechecked to see whether the fork is done correctly_ how? An `strace -f …` of the Mac OS run could be interesting.

Comment: I've checked the return value of fork() and it returns normal pid.

Comment: For clarification, i used dtruss to check the syscall the program does fork correctly but the child process is never scheduled.